# binding img src dynamically using vue3

Tags: url, binding, vuejs3

i want to pass an img url from component to another and bind it dynamically but every time i got 404 not (the path is correct )
**first Component:**
<a
@click="
details(
'../assets/images/references/batiment/batiment-project1.svg',
'../assets/images/references/batiment/batimentProject2.svg',
'../assets/images/references/batiment/batimentProject3.svg',
'../assets/images/references/batiment/batimentProject4.svg'
)
"
>En savoir plus</a
>

```
 details(image111, image222, image333, image444) {
  this.image11 = image111;
  this.image22 = image222;
  this.image33 = image333;
  this.image44 = image444;
  new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("staticBackdrop")).show();
},
```

**second component**

```
          <img class="col-4" width="100%" v-bind:src="image2" alt="" />
 props: {
image1: String,
image2: String,
image3: String,
image4: String,
```

},

Answer (score 0):

Are these components stored in the same directory? If not, it could cause this issue. Try to use `'@/assets/images/references/batiment/batiment-project1.svg'` instead of `'../assets/images/references/batiment/batiment-project1.svg'`. In `vue3` `@` means `src` folder.

Comment: these components are in the same folder. i tried using '@/assets/images/references/batiment/batiment-project1.svg' instead of '../assets/images/references/batiment/batiment-project1.svg' but same error